# How to make HTML table in borders as it displaying organized data with below code in Python

Tags: python, email

I have used this piece of code with Python 2.6, Email seems to be working, HTML table is displaying organized data, but there are no borders around it to make it actually table visually. Could you please suggest what needs to be done here?

```
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

me = 'xxx@gmail.com'
password = 'yyyzzz!!2'
server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
you = 'qqq@gmail.com'

text = """
Hello, Friend.

Here is your data:

{table}

Regards,

Me"""

html = """
<html>
 <body>
  <p>Hello, Friend.</p>
  <p>Here is your data:</p>
  {table}
  <p>Regards,</p>
  <p>Me</p>
 </body>
</html>
"""

with open('input.csv') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    data = list(reader)

text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))

message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])

message['Subject'] = "Your data"
message['From'] = me
message['To'] = you
server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(me, password)
server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
server.quit()
```